# Como é que a informação de charts poderão ser querys de sql?

Tags: javascript, html, chart

A minha dúvida consiste na criação de um chart de linhas onde cada valor é uma query que eu já construi!

Estou a utilizar o phpmyadmin que tem a BD (importada de um ficheiro sql)
E estou a usar:

> link rel="stylesheet"href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css"

e

> script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"

para criar os graficos!
Os labels são os meses do ano ou até mesmo os anos mas as series são as tais querys de sql que já tenho..

Ainda não tenho código para colocar aqui como dúvida, só queria uma ideia geral de como fazer para me guiar e orientar
A minha pergunta é, basta separar por virgulas as querys dentro das chavetas das series?

Answer (score 0):

Eu já utilizei os charts do google, acho que vai te atender legal.
https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda mas fiquei na mesma situação... O meu problema aqui é que os meus valores para colocar no gráfico são querys que já fiz em sql